# Unity. When installing builded apk on my tablet, game scenes do Not loading, while in the pc unity they are loading

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, scene

1. video link demonstrating the problem: [Shown: problem, settings, code and logic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PX0YJnFgp0s&ab_channel=Arothron)
   quick screenshots:
2. ["Edit - Preferences - External Tools": what i changed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25O9r.png)
3. [file - Build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY1G1.png)
4. [edit - project settings - player - publishing settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9osN.png)
5. [edit - project settings - player - other settings (not all)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLtTL.png)
6. ["Levels" button, script location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BByEz.png)
7. [level menu, all the scenes, lvl button's logic and it's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V43H.png)
8. Other links are in the comments of this post becouse stackoverflow won't let me post more than 8 links in the reason of my low reputation. It must be here, unless this site shadow ban my links.

Caution: links at the top are marked with their serial numbers, which i will refer to in the text below.

To successfully build my unity project without any errors which i received earlier i followed guide from link N8. I checked boxes "custom base gradle template" and "custom gradle properties template" in "edit - project settings - player - publishing settings" (screenshot N10). Also i changed name of the "sdk/build-tools" some of it's versions file named "d8.bat" to "dx.bat" both at it's main foulder and "main/lib" foulder (screenshot N9). Also i changed baseProjectTemplate.gradle and gradleTemplate.properties in "project/Assets/Plugins/Android" (screenshot N11 and N12) after their appearance in this foulder after i checked the boxes in "edit - project settings - player - publishing settings" (screenshot N10). I also installed in android studio Android SDK settings ("Android studio - sdk manager  (or "file - settings") - Appearance & Behaviour - System Settings - Android SDK") SDK platforms from android 25 to latest android and in SDK tools i installed Android SDK Build-Tools "25, 30, 31, 32 AND the latest version".
These are the highlights. You can find the rest of what I did in the link N8, as i followed the instructions completely.

Description of the problem:

The game have a main menu where at the startup the only button "Levels" shows up. At press, main menu swithes to lvl menu where all the level buttons and a "Main menu" button. When one of these lvl buttons are pressed, the logic (screenshot N7) and code below will run (screenshot N7).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GoToLvlButton : MonoBehaviour{
    public Object scene;
    public void GoToSceneScene(){
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(scene.name);
    };
};
```

In pc unity it works perfectly (video at N1) but when i build it (file - build settings - build), share my apk to my device (Huawei MediaPad M5 Lite 10 LTE "BAH2-L09", EMUI - 8.0.0, Android 8.0.0 (Oreo) API - 26), install and run it at this device, the "Levels" and "Main menu" buttons works fine, but when i click to other buttons in lvl menu, it clicks, but nothing happens.

All scenes already added to "file - build settings - Scenes in build" (screenshot N3).

I tried installing absolutely everything in "Android studio - sdk manager  (or "file - settings") - Appearance & Behaviour - System Settings - Android SDK", but it didnt helped. I also several times completely reinstalled all unity hub and it's editors. I tried to install almost everything in additional installations in vs installing. I tried to install almost all modules to my 2022.3.4f1 unity engine. I watched a lot of tutorials, guides and even find two similar posts in two different sites (stackoverflow.com and unity.com), but they didn't helped me too. Tried to clear cache of my project. I tried to install other unity editor versions. I tried to change Minimum API Level and Target API Level to Android 8.0 'Oreo' (API level 26) (becouse it is my device android version) in "edit - project settings - player - other settings" (screenshot N5) but apk build fails no matter what i do.

I expected that when i run my game in my android device it will load scenes, as it do in pc, but it doesn't. My thoughts that problem in the script itself.
I really need to run this game properly in my tablet, even if i need to recode all scripts. Thanks for reading.

Comment: i understand that i can paste here my png links

Comment: 8) following screenshots showing what do i changed to build succesfully my game, from this guide [guide](https://codeprofessionally.com/gradle-build-failed-unity)
9) [what i changed in "sdk/build-tools" in some it's versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pX5F.png)
10) ["edit - project settings - player - publishing settings" and what boxes do i check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUVXa.png)
11) [baseProjectTemplate.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlgwW.png)
12) [gradleTemplate.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziUmQ.png)

Comment: what happens if you change it from dropping the scene in a field, to entering the text of the name? or the number in the build does it work then?

Comment: @BugFinder ok... when i put pure string in LoadScene it works, but when i try to get exact same string from my object (the ASCII the same of this two strings)  it doesn't work (at android)... When i tried to build my project with this object converted to SceneAsset, console said that "build failed" and "The name 'sceneAsset' does not exist in the current context" and a few more similar errors to this one, like "sceneAsset" class didn't exist. But it errors only at build, not when i run game at pc, where all works fine!

Comment: Ok so you have a way forward. Just not the one you want. Im not at a machine but i can imagine scenes arent stored in a manner like prefabs. Because you also stored it as an object.  There is a lot that works in the ide but not in build

Comment: @BugFinder Sorry, i can't close my post now, becouse i am 1000 km away from home. I also didn't understand well how can i do it what you said above, so can you give me a link with a guide, or explain it here, please? For me also possible to put a pure string into gameobject's script, but I don't want to do it becouse it not convenient.

Comment: You already said you did it and it worked..  All you need to do then is put strings where you have objects  for scenes

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you for help very much! Me, as perfectionist and a laziest coder of all time, of course will have existential crisis every time i have to write a whole string into this field (not to drag scene here, emotional damage), but you still saved my life. Idk i was struggling with this problem like 1 month. I would like your post but I can't do this becouse of my (again) reputation, so i can't do much to help you instead. Thanks you again, BugFinder!